# How long is an Azure Search Query cached for?

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

We were performance tuning our app and the azure query response times. We started noticing the significant lowered latency times for cached queries. Every cached query ran 5 times as fast. My question to you is how long are those queries cached in azure search for? 
We were thinking along the lines of keeping our azure queries for home page load "warm"/"cached" by hitting it with a warm up service.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

We do cache filters and facets, so if your queries use either of those, you will see a performance improvement by warming them up first. Also, all caching are size based, rather than time based. So depending on the traffic your service generate, the time your values will be kept in the cache will vary. Because of this, we cannot guarantee a minimum interval for your warm up service. My recommendation would be to go trough trial and error until you find the right time interval that fit your service's usage pattern.

Comment: Is there an article to determine search patterns and how to warm-up the indexes ? When you say warm-up in the context of a Search, do you mean some sort of preference cache like file, request or query ? Please let me know.

Comment: Hi Kaushik, what I meant by warming up the cache is that segments of the indexes that that are often accessed are more likely to be kept in memory, speeding up their retrieval. For example, if a website using Azure Search uses faceted navigation, subsequent queries returning the same facets will likely complete faster than a query retrieving those facets for the first time.

Comment: While there is no explicit configuration that allows users to change caching behavior, changing the configuration of your cluster will have an effect on the caching capability of your search service. For example, upgrading to a higher SKU will give access to more memory, allowing better caching. Increasing the number of partitions should also have a positive effect on caching as it will also increase the total amount of memory available for caching.